# each function to create img elements out of array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need some support with this one. I have an array:

```
var imageArr = [
    { someobject: '..', anotherobject: '..', img: 'SourceOfFirstImg.jpg'}, 
    { someobject: '..', anotherobject: '..', img: 'SourceOfSecondImg.jpg'},
    // 100 times
]
```

and what I want to do is create an `.each()` function to create `<img>` elements, fill them with each link src and append them to a div. I does not need necessarely `each()` if there is a plain JS way it is fine too.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`map` method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) to create an array of image elements to append:

```
$('.somediv').append($.map(imageArr, function(o){
  return $('<img>', { src: o.img });
}));
```

Comment: how is it with the performance, I'm thinking about what could be the performant way of all answers. Could you say something about it? ps. yours works pretty well, thats why I'm asking

Comment: As for performance, you may wish to experiment with [JS Perf](http://jsperf.com), performance comparison is its one reason for existing.

Comment: @supersize: All solutions would perform pretty much the same, if you just cache the target element if you are using a loop to append the images. You might gain a few percent by using more plain Javascript than jQuery, but you loose compatibility. The `.forEach` method for example doesn't work in IE 8.

Answer (score 1):

```
var imageArr = [
                { someobject: '..', anotherobject: '..', img: 'SourceOfFirstImg.jpg'}, 
                { someobject: '..', anotherobject: '..', img: 'SourceOfSecondImg.jpg'},
                // 100 times
               ]
for (var i = 0; i < imageArr.length; i++) {
     var img = $('<img class="foo" >'); 
     img.attr('src', imageArr[i].img);
     $('body').append(img);

};
```

Answer (score 1):

At its simplest, I'd suggest:

```
var imageArray = [{
    'alt': 'Alt text',
        'src': 'http://placekitten.com/200/200',
        'title': 'Title text'
}, {
    'alt': 'More alt text',
        'src': 'http://lorempixel.com/200/200',
        'title': 'Yet another title attribute'
}],
    target = document.body,
    img;

imageArray.forEach(function(a){
    img = document.createElement('img');
    for (var prop in a) {
        if (a.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            img[prop] = a[prop];
        }
    }
    target.appendChild(img);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/cvy33/).

**Edited** to use the OP's posted `imageArr`:

```
var imageArr = [{
    someobject: '..',
    anotherobject: '..',
    img: 'SourceOfFirstImg.jpg'
}, {
    someobject: '..',
    anotherobject: '..',
    img: 'SourceOfSecondImg.jpg'
}],
    target = document.body,
    img;

imageArr.forEach(function (a) {
    img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = a.img;
    target.appendChild(img);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/cvy33/1/).

References:

- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement).
- [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in).
- [`Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty).

Comment: I already have the structure of an array, could you adjust the answer to my OP? Would be awesome!

Comment: Sure, but since you've only specified one useful attribute for an image (and called it by a non-HTMLImgElement property) it's a little less useful so far as I can tell, but it depends what you're doing I suppose. Anyway: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/cvy33/1/).

Comment: thanks for both answers. To come back to the performance thing, can I pressume that plain JS is a bit faster than the `.map()` method? I know that you posted the jsPerf site but just to have a raw guess.

Comment: jQuery is pretty well optimised for efficiency, but it's still an abstraction of underlying JavaScript, which means there are (perhaps many) function/method-calls beyond those required if it were written in 'plain' JavaScript. But, honestly, you'll rarely notice the additional cost of those calls (and developer time is often more expensive than the cost of any inefficiencies, see "[Hardware is Cheap, Programmers are Expensive](http://blog.codinghorror.com/hardware-is-cheap-programmers-are-expensive/).")

Comment: haha, thanks for the info! I will give the `.map()` method the accepted answer since I'm more familiar with jQuery and plain JS is kind of new for me (yeah yeah, always these Library users) but I really appreciate your detailed answer, learned a lot new!

Comment: I'm glad to have been of help! And don't worry about preferring jQuery, I learned to use jQuery long before I started to learn how to use JavaScript/DOM properly (and, frankly, more or less by accident).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var imageArr = [
    { someobject: '..', anotherobject: '..', img: 'http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/Rcd/K5B/RcdK5Bbgi.png'}, 
    { someobject: '..', anotherobject: '..', img: 'http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/Rcd/K5B/RcdK5Bbgi.png'},
]
var div = document.createElement("div");
for(i = 0; i< imageArr.length; i++)
{
   var img = document.createElement("img");
   img.setAttribute("src",imageArr[i].img);
   div.appendChild(img);
}
alert(div.innerHTML);
```

### Here is the **<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/S5Ku3/)</kbd>**